# Lua: Gmatch to string

Tags: lua, string-matching

I am new to lua, I need to get a value from gmatch and turn it into a string.

```
string.gmatch(source, pattern)
```

To

```
if args.Produces then
    if (args.Produces == '') then args.Produces = STRING end
...
```

How can I do this? All my attempts turn it into a function or table, but I just need the one string.

Comment: I think you want `string.match`

Comment: `need to get a value from gmatch and turn it into a string` Question is not Clear. string.match returns the matched text, or nil if the pattern is not found. Be more clear with Question

Comment: `string.gmatch` returns an iterator function, so you could loop through and find what you need.  But, as wsha stated, the question is not clear and I don't have any idea what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Give you an example, is it helpful?

```
local pair = "name = Anna"
local key, value = string.match(pair, "(%a+)%s*=%s*(%a+)")
print(key, value) -- name   Anna
```